# How do you run JUnit tests in Flatpak Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit, flatpak

I have Eclipse installed as a Flatpak via [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.eclipse.Java). When I try to run a JUnit 4 suite defined to run all tests within a project, it fails with this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot read testname file.
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

I looked into the source for `RemoteTestRunner` and found that it is trying to read a file whose path was provided to the runner:

```
            else if("-testnamefile".equals(args[i].toLowerCase())) { //$NON-NLS-1$
                String testNameFile= args[i+1];
                try {
                    readTestNames(testNameFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot read testname file.");        //$NON-NLS-1$
                }
                i++;

            }
```

[Source link](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/724f841f19160133a493dfb33d36ee550b219857/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/RemoteTestRunner.java#L261-L269)

So I examined the command line for the test execution and did find that argument:

```
-testNameFile /tmp/testNames8297875472451881369.txt
```

The exception message isn't lying - that file does not exist. The name of the file changes each time it is run, but the file is never created.

I verified from a terminal inside Eclipse and from the Flatpak container via `flatpak run --command=sh org.eclipse.Java` that I can create, modify, and delete files at `/tmp`.

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure what is supposed to create this temporary file with the test names in it or why it is failing to do so. I see no evidence in Eclipse logs of a failure to write this file. Permissions don't seem to be an issue.

One last observation I did make is that when I open a terminal inside Eclipse and run `ls -al /tmp` I see all the files from my host machine's `/tmp` directory. I thought Flatpak specifically blocked `/tmp` [even when file permissions are set to host](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html#filesystem-access). However, when I run the sandbox from a terminal (using `flatpak run`), I see a sandbox version of `/tmp` that does not match the host. In either case, I can read, write, and modify files in `/tmp`.

Comment: I posted this on the [Eclipse Flatpak GitHub project](https://github.com/flathub/org.eclipse.Java/issues/42) since I'm now thinking this might be a bug rather than a configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in the Flatpak permissions and not a configuration issue. This was resolved by the team maintaining the Eclipse Flatpak quickly.

For those that are interested, the Flatpak needed to request read/write access to `/tmp`.

Here is the issue: https://github.com/flathub/org.eclipse.Java/issues/42

Here is the pull request that fixed it: https://github.com/flathub/org.eclipse.Java/pull/43